# Twitter Bootstrap Image Sprites (certain one's not displaying)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap with a Rails 3.2 App and wondering if this is a known issue --

Certain Icon glyphs work and certain one's dont.

For example, works fine:

```
 <i class="icon-volume-up"> </i>
```

And,

```
  <i class=" icon-bullhorn"> </i>
```

...doesn't.

Both are valid image icons listed on their [site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html)

Is this a known issue?

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Not](http://jsfiddle.net/6wDp7/1/)** an issue. However, the version on their site refers to Twitter Bootstrap **v2.1.0**, which uses the latest Glyphicons sprite (**1.6**), which does indeed contain `icon-bullhorn`.

Previous to Twitter Bootstrap [v2.0.3](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.0.3/img/glyphicons-halflings.png), `icon-bullhorn` did [*not*](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.0.2/img/glyphicons-halflings.png) exist, and that's why you do not see it.

Make sure you have the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap, or at least, the latest version of  `sprites.less` and `glyphicons-halflings.png`.